# PQ Array causing stuck on golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I have this `GO` code which will insert 2 string and an array to PostgreSQL

```
package main

import (
    "backend_hotel/modules"
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB
var Cancel context.CancelFunc

func main() {
    modules.InitiateGlobalVariables(false)

    var errDB error
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        modules.MapConfig["rhanovDatabaseHost"],
        modules.MapConfig["rhanovDatabasePort"],
        modules.MapConfig["rhanovDatabaseUser"],
        modules.MapConfig["rhanovDatabasePass"],
        modules.MapConfig["rhanovDatabaseName"])
    db, errDB = sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if errDB != nil {
        modules.DoLog("INFO", "", "HotelUserDB", "main",
            "Failed to connect to database Rhanov server. Error!", true, errDB)
        panic(errDB)
    } else {
        modules.DoLog("INFO", "", "HotelUserDB", "main",
            "Success to connect to database Rhanov.", false, nil)
    }

    insertQuery := `INSERT INTO user_history.last_multi_flight_search(user_id, query_string, flight_ids) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`

    fmt.Println("sampe A")

    insertArray := []string{"Test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4", "test 5"}

    result, err := db.Exec(insertQuery, "001", "iniQueryString", pq.Array(insertArray))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("sampe B")
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("sampe C")
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
    fmt.Println("sampe D")
}
```

but I have always stuck when it reached checkpoint A, which is strange... what should I do PS : I have tried to insert without array & do select statement, and it returned no error

Comment: what you mean by `always stuck when it reached checkpoint A`. The execution is stopped or waiting for long? Do you receiving any error?

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason the driver seems to stuck if i insert an ID which exist in the table, but when i insert it with a different user_id, it works just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).